# Options for upload files bigger than 2Gb using web browser

Tags: silverlight, flash, file-upload

Good day!

I'm looking for options on uploading really big files (over 2Gb) using web browsers. I know that Java applet solutions will work, I know (and have tested by myself) that Flash has internal limitation about 2Gb. What about Silverlight? Have I missed some way\technology of doing this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I really hope you find a good answer to this, but in my experience, a good FTP server usually solves the issue.  Of course, this may be unacceptable depending on your users and situation.

Comment: Emphasis on "good".  Crappy servers like to assume 32-bit file sizes.

Comment: Hi artvolk, did you ever find a solution to this? I think breaking the file up into little pieces will negate the whole file size limit won't it?

Comment: For now we haven't found any solution except creating our custom client in form of a desktop app. The Google Gears works too but they are not widely used.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge upload in .NET 4 is limited to "2097151" (2 GB). It could be set in web.config

```
<system.web>
  <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2097151" />
</system.web>
```

OK, so there's another idea: you can upload files in chunks.
There's a [project](http://silverlightfileupld.codeplex.com/) on codeplex that might be of use to you.

Comment: The server side is on nginx with upload module (which can handle files more than 2Gb via Google Gears, for example) not ASP.NET. The problem is on the client. Silverlight seems to be an option only if partial uploads are used. It can't handle more that 2Gb at once too (even start to send it to the server).

Answer (score 0):

(For Flash) Split the file into fixed sized chunks (maybe 10-50 MB each) of byte-arrays in the flash client, not too hard with the ByteArray class.

Now you can upload each chunk and the server can puzzle them together. Another plus to this is that if the client is ever disconnected, the server knows which parts of that file the user has already sent and the user can just continue from almost where he left.

You could even send multiple chunks at once (between 2 and 4, each browser has different max connection count), gaining better network utilization.

Comment: Thanks for the answer in this old thread, do you have any links to working example?

Comment: No, sorry :( (and sorry for a really really late reply)

Answer (score -2):

You can split the file into parts using 7zip, then upload load the parts as per usual.

Comment: And how would you do this programmatically, client-side?  Furthermore, there would be huge overhead in zipping.

Comment: Yes, I was looking for programmatically solution for client side.